# What is a Green Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Green Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Green Words™ | Not Green Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BASKETBALL | SOLITAIRE |
| CATCH | APPRECIATE |
| WEST | EAST |
| NAME | AGE |
| ATTACH | SPARE |
| LOVE | CABRIOLETS |
| ANARCHY | TITLE |
| CRY | GLAD |
| FLEXIBLE | OBJECT |
| JOKER | LOLLIPOP |

Comment: **7** upvotes and a reputation of **777**, and my lucky number is **7**. I like this post!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Glad to hear that :)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ...but if you like it, there will be 8 upvotes :(

Comment: @the4kman Well, how could you be so sure that the 7th isn't mine?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is correct, but

> It seems to me that all the words on the left side have atleast one letter in the word that has an opening at the top. Like a cup for rain. The Y, H,V, M, N, K, X.  Or perhaps that is just a clue to what the real rule is. All the words on the right exclude these letters.

Comment: Basketball should've been on the right by this rule.

Comment: @padawan I don't think so

Comment: @padawan Sorry, I mistyped and left out the K. The K follows that rule too. I've added it back in now.

Comment: Yes, I was just going to write that :) It works.

Comment: Very good. For what it's worth, ENVY has three open-top letters and a connection to green. (No "real" vowels have open tops, but HYMN and WHY are words that are made up exclusively of such letters.)

Comment: @MOehm Wouldn't you say that U has an open top though? So that might could be used to make more words.

Comment: Yes, I'm silly. Most of the U's I've seen have open tops. `:)` (That makes my nice little theory about envy look rather silly, too. Sorry about that.)

Comment: @MOehm If I can forget about a K, then you can forget about a U too `;)`

Comment: J has an open top, so OBJECT should go on the left.

Comment: @MarkTilford Yeah I was wondering about that too when coming up with the answer. But that's why I said opening at the top of the letter. The cup for the J is at the bottom. But that's what also made me unsure of my answer.

Comment: considering capital letter J, we usually write like this > https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MzQCbX_7wDs/maxresdefault.jpg that's why i used J in not green column. I don't know if its wrong.

Comment: Anyways congratulations :)

Comment: @ran Thanks! I am curious though, why did you choose the word Green to describe it?

Comment: Green means eco-friendly. Rainwater harvesting can be connected to this which is a method to protect our nature. :)